# Monitor isn't being detected

Tags: xorg, ati, resolution, monitor

Hey guys i'm having a problem with my monitor.. I just installed ubuntu 11.10 and the monitor appears to be unknown with a resolution of 800x600..  When I install the discrete graphics card driver ATI the system reboots and now the monitor won't even turn up because of wrong refresh rates =\

My question is.. Is there a way to force a resolution without the xrandr commands? I mean by writing down on xorg.conf someway because i did that and it didn't worked, I already tried those commands aticonfig --initial etc... and edited again the xorg.conf and still not works.

I managed to solve this problem on windows by entering the safe mode with low resolution and forcing up the 1920x1080 with 60hz. But in Ubuntu It so much complicated I can't solve it I'm almost giving up ;\

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us what kind of monitor you have.

Answer (score 0):

Is the monitor connect through VGA or DVI - DVI is better as it supports more detailed 
communication between the graphics chip & monitor.